# react-image-crop and scale

Tags: reactjs, react-image-crop

so i am using the react-image-crop with kotlin js, i have it working on a vanilla implementation without any css transformation...

i am having issues when it has been modified by css

i am using the crop preview from the example (the best i could convert it to kotlin-react)

fun cropPreview(
image: HTMLImageElement,
canvas: HTMLCanvasElement,
crop: PixelCrop,
scale: Double = 1.0,
rotate: Double = 0.0,
) {
var _scale = scale
val ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as? CanvasRenderingContext2D ?: throw Error("No 2d context")
val scaleX:Double = (image.naturalWidth / image.width).toDouble()
val scaleY:Double = (image.naturalHeight / image.height).toDouble()
val pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio

```
canvas.width = floor(crop.width * scaleX * pixelRatio).toInt()
canvas.height = floor(crop.height * scaleY * pixelRatio).toInt()

ctx.scale(pixelRatio, pixelRatio)
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = ImageSmoothingQuality.HIGH

val cropX = crop.x * scaleX
val cropY = crop.y * scaleY

val rotateRads = rotate * TO_RADIANS
val centerX:Double = (image.naturalWidth / 2).toDouble()
val centerY:Double = (image.naturalHeight / 2).toDouble()

ctx.save()
ctx.translate(-cropX, -cropY)
ctx.translate(centerX, centerY)
ctx.rotate(rotateRads)
ctx.scale(_scale, _scale)
ctx.translate(-centerX, -centerY)
ctx.drawImage(
    image,
    0.0,
    0.0,
    image.naturalWidth.toDouble(),
    image.naturalHeight.toDouble(),
    0.0,
    0.0,
    image.naturalWidth.toDouble(),
    image.naturalHeight.toDouble(),
)

ctx.restore()
// console.log("try me", canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
```

}

the scale value i am sending in is not from a user controlled input though.. i am taking the desired width (post transform) and dividing that by the natural width (non transformed)

```
 (700.0 / width).coerceAtMost(1.0)
```

but when i use that value the preview is off.

Is scale not used the way i think it is?  I know i am probably overlooking something basic.

All help is appreciated

Unrelated to this question but will help folks having issues with the library....

**IF YOU ARE USING THIS LIBRARY AND HAVING ISSUES, i cannot recommend stripping out all css.  I was using this in a bootstrap container and it was causing issues...**